# Why does Prism navigationService.NavigateAsync not return exceptions in the INavigationResult?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism-7

All of a sudden, my Prism 7.1-based Xamarin Forms app (4.1) is not handling exceptions in any of the INavigationAware methods. What *used* to happen is that the INavigationResult that was returned from the NavigateAsync method would have its "Success" property set to false if something untoward happened in the target page's viewmodel, and I could react accordingly by inspecting the "Exception" property.

Now, all of a sudden, exceptions in the target view/view model INavigationAware implementations are unhandled and are causing my app to crash. I created a small test project and it works as expected with the same Prism and XF packages installed. I am completely baffled by this now.

What on earth could be happening? I've cleaned all the projects, deleted obj and bin folders, restarted VS multiple times, rebooted devices, everything I can think of.

Comment: OK, so my test app wasn't completely the "same" as my actual app. In my actual app, I made my OnNavigatingTo method async. My test app wasn't async, and when I did that, I get the same crash behavior.

Comment: I think it may be a Prism vs. XF4 issue. Going to try to upgrade to Prism 7.2.

Comment: OK, it's clearly a case of marking the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatingTo methods as "async void." So, what is the best practice for performing async tasks in these INavigationAware methods while still being able to leverage the INavigationResult that's returned in the Task when I call INavigationService.NavigateAsync()? Is there some other page lifecycle method that I'm not aware of where I should be calling these async operations?